# Isabelle: Use of the "induct" or "induct_tac" methods

Tags: isabelle, apply-script

Let's say I have a lemma about a simple inductively-defined set:

```
inductive_set foo :: "'a ⇒ 'a list set" for x :: 'a where
  "[] ∈ foo x" | "[x] ∈ foo x"

lemma "⋀x y. y ∈ foo x ⟹ qux x y ⟹ baz x y"
```

(It's important to me that the "⋀x y" bit stays, because the lemma is actually stating the state of my proof in the middle of a long apply chain.)

I'm having trouble starting the proof of this lemma. I would like to proceed by rule induction.

### First attempt

I tried writing

```
apply (induct rule: foo.induct)
```

but that doesn't work: the `induct` method fails. I find I can get around this by fixing `x` and `y` explicitly, and then invoking the `induct` method, like so:

```
proof -
  fix x :: 'a
  fix y :: "'a list"
  assume "y ∈ foo x" and "qux x y"
  thus "baz x y"
  apply (induct rule: foo.induct)
oops
```

However, since I'm actually in the middle of an apply chain, I would rather not enter a structured proof block.

### Second attempt

I tried using the `induct_tac` method instead, but unfortunately `induct_tac` does not apply the `foo.induct` rule in the way I would like. If I type

```
apply (induct_tac rule: foo.induct, assumption)
```

then the first subgoal is

```
⋀x y. y ∈ foo x ⟹ qux x y ⟹ baz x []
```

which is not what I want: I wanted `qux x []` instead of `qux x y`. The `induct` method got this right, but had other problems, discussed above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you first transform your goal to look like this:

```
⋀x y. y ∈ foo x ⟹ qux x y ⟶ baz x []
```

then `apply (induct_tac rule: foo.induct)` will instantiate the induction rule in the way that you want. (It will also leave the object-level implications in the resulting goals, to which you will need to `apply (rule impI)`.)

The `induct` method does these extra steps dealing with implications automatically, which is one of its major advantages.

On the other hand, `induct_tac rule: foo.induct` doesn't do anything more than `apply (rule foo.induct)`. (In general, `induct_tac` can match the variables you specify, and automatically choose an induction rule based on their types, but you're not taking advantage of those features here.)

I think your best option is to go ahead and use a proof block at the end of your apply chain. If you are worried that all the `fix`, `assume` and `show` statements are too verbose, then you can use the little-advertised `case goaln` feature:

```
apply ...
apply ...
proof -
  case goal1 thus ?case
    apply induct
    ...
qed
```